# Error message when creating a site template

Tags: error, site-template

I have a page and I am trying to create a template because it will be use multiple times (Parent) and will have sub-sites (Children). I went to Site Actions --> Site Settings --> Site Actions --> Save site as template. Then I completed the fields and selected 'OK'. The site was processing, then displayed an error message.

> Error
> An unexpected error has occurred.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.
>
> Correlation ID: f37b1d39-5732-4dd2-b765-14b1138673f6
>
> Date and Time: 6/1/2011 11:23:09 AM
>
> Go back to site

I am wondering if the data that was inserted may have to be removed before I can create a template?

Comment: You can use SP client browser and delete those fields (if they are orphan BCS fields) under the _hidden group

You can download SP Client Browser here: https://spcb.codeplex.com/releases?ReleaseId=110899

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the ULS logs normally defaulted to c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\logs but could be moved by the admin and search for the correlation ID this will give you a better description of the error. Generally data is not included unless you select to include it when creating the template.

Comment: I had done this yesterday and I used textpad and notepad to open the logs and there was nothing readable.

Comment: Make sure you are using the log files and not the .usage files that are generated during that time period. notepad should open the log files. Verify the location in Central Admin under Monitoring>Configure Diagnostic Log Settings.

Comment: Yes, the path is correct and I am viewing the log. This is what I found: 'Missing one or more of the following attributes from the root node in solution Action Plan.wsp: assembly '', type ''. 316013cb-da82-4e0c-8320-f9c7f5d16233 SPSolutionExporter: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: Feature definition with Id f41b07a8-a5ac-4f8c-802e-216a48b71871 failed validation, file '1ActionPlanListInstances\ElementsFields.xml', line 3166, character 82: The 'BdcField' attribute is not allowed. at Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPSolutionPackage.SolutionFile.Feat' There is much more like this. -sighs-

Comment: So, it looks like to me that I need to get in the code and figure out what is going on! LOL, guess I am REALLY getting a learning experience here. Don't know where to begin, but I will poke around until I do. :)